# How can I make an OS X application unfocusable while still receiving click events?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, nswindow, nspanel

I'm developing an on screen keyboard application for OS X, similar to the one that's built in to the operating system (Keyboard Viewer). I seem to have hit a wall as I'm not sure how I can accept click events from buttons and not steal focus from the currently activated application. I know this is possible since there are apps that already do this, e.g. AssistiveWere's KeyStrokes.

So my question is this: How can I make my window receive mouse events and handle them without getting activated?

P.S. I'm not very experienced in OS X development and this is my first Swift project, so excuses if this is a trivial problem.

Comment: You need to be able to have permission of the user to have Accessibility access. After that you need to register a NotificationListener to receive keyboard and mouse events on the OS/System scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your window an instance of `NSPanel` (or a subclass), include `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` in its `styleMask`, and set `becomesKeyOnlyIfNeeded` to true. (The style mask can be controlled in IB.) You probably also want it to be floating so it's always above normal windows, so set `floatingPanel` to true, too.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the thing I needed!